# Unable to receive DHCP address

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm unable to receive a DHCP address from the server on the network.  Currently this is what I get if I have dhcp enabled from the ethernet adapter status:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5471:619:8e1b:ee9b%14  
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.238.155  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

I've tried to restart DHCP services but I get access denied.  I've updated permissions in the registry like many tutorials suggest.

Here's where it gets odd.  If I set a static address, I'm able to get access the internet.  As soon as I set it back to dhcp I get an address from my dhcp server as shown below:

```
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5471:619:8e1b:ee9b%14  
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.142  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Seconds later, it reverts back to the autoconfigured IP address.  It seems that some other service is affecting the DHCP.

Not sure how to troubleshoot furture from here.  I have turned on dhcp client logging.  Is that something I should post?

Comment: this can happen to windows if the IP is detected to be a duplicate. we once had an issue with vmware switches that caused false detection of duplicate IPs. what happens if you set a reservation in the dhcp server for this box that is the same as the working static IP. does dhcp work then?

Comment: It might also be possible that you have two conflicting DHCP servers in your local network, for example a modem and a router.

Comment: Hey Thomas,  Thanks for the response.  I tried assigning an IP to the box from the dhcp server.  Initially it took that ip and then reverted back to autoassigned.

Comment: So the IP that works if you set it as static, fails if it is pushed via DHCP. what is your DHCP lease time? are there plenty of addresses in the pool, and they are in the same IP range as the rest of the LAN being served, right?  Are any logs appearing in EventVwr? your DHCP client logs may be useful, but I believe the issue is your NIC reacting to an exceptional condition either in the nic or the switch/AP its connected to, causing the nic to fall back to zeroconf config.

Comment: also do you use any zeroconf software like Apple Bonjour (installed with iTunes)? is there a service running called `WLAN Autoconfig`? does behavior change if you disable it?

Comment: Hey Frank,  I went in and check and it looks like dhcp lease time was set to 0.  I'm guessing that happened when I updated to the newest firmware.  I updated it and now everything is great.  I appreciate your help.